# How to insert image in status bar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I want to create an image in my statusbar, but why it can't appear?
And, how to add menu in status bar when I click right the mouse?

This is my script:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
# Fungsi dari file ini adalah mengatur tampilan dan perilaku addon.
# Membuat menu "search hadits" pada saat user klik kanan pada halaman browser atau
# pada saat user klik kanan pada kata di halaman browser.
-->
<overlay id="inline_trans"
xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">


    <!--
    # Membuat Menu Klik kanan pada halaman firefox.
    # Memanggil fungsi pada haditsSearch.js untuk mulai melakukan pencarian hadits.
    -->
    <popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
        <menuitem class="inlinetrans" id="inlineContext" oncommand= "hadits_mean.startFind(null);"
        label="Cari Terjemahan"/>
    </popup>
    <!-- ======================================================== -->
<!--

    <window id="main-window">
    <popupset id="mainPopupSet"></popupset>
    <vbox id="hadits_holder" />
    </window>

    -->
<!--
    <spacer flex="1"/>
    <progressmeter mode="determined" value="82"/>
-->
    <statusbar id="status-bar">
      <statusbarpanel id="status-bar-inlinetrans"
       src="chrome://inlinetrans/skin/imagesOn_kecil.png"
       label="indonesia inline translator"
       context="indonesia inline translator menu"
       onclick="alert('okeh cuy')"
       tooltiptext="inlinetrans versi 1.0"
       />
    </statusbar>


</overlay>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `<image>`. Something like:

```
<statusbar id="status-bar">
  <statusbarpanel id="status-bar-inlinetrans">
    <image src="chrome://inlinetrans/skin/imagesOn_kecil.png" />
  </statusbarpanel>
</statusbar>
```

The other attributes can probably go on either the image or the statusbarpanel.

Comment: I was wrong, you can add the image URL directly to the statusbar panel, but in that case, the attribute is called `image`, not `src`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/statusbarpanel#a-image